# Как с точки зрения кода реализована система активностей в Discord?

Tags: discord, tcp, очередь, диспетчер-задач

Меня очень интересует система активностей в Discord. Когда у тебя в профиле отображается в каком ты приложении, а само приложение может отправлять клиенту Discord какую-либо информацию о твоём статусе (какой файл открыт, сколько ты играешь, сколько раундов из скольких и т. д.). Я начал изучать вопрос, но единственное что я нашёл - это как понять для своей программы, что запущено через что-то вроде OBS/Steam. Но я нашёл максимально близкие вещи для подобной реализации:

- Локальные TCP сервера через порт или сокет-файл
- Системные межпроцессорные очереди через операционную систему
- Использование сигнатуры диспетчера задач

Максимально заманчивым выглядит первый вариант, но его легко внешне скомпрометировать. Второй вариант тоже неплох, но тоже может быть скомпрометирован и в случае сброса задачи, получатель не узнает что нужно прекратить отображение этого процесса. Третий вариант надёжный, но очень муторный. Это нужно же вручную каждый процесс проверять.

Я изначально думал, что Discord использует TCP-сервера локальные, но не нашёл его порта с списке условно-зарезервированных портов. Даже у Steam есть (`1200/UDP`, `1725/UDP`, `27018`), что логично. Попробовал поиграться с системными очередями, +- неплохо работали при уведомлении об отключении, но только на Windows и Linux. На Android мне запрещали создавать, если явно не включить рут. Третий вариант я даже не пробовал, но сомневаюсь, что он может показать что-то эффективное и простое. Но в тоже время отображение статуса мобильных игр в Discord работает только через Game Launcher. Значит нужно копать в сторону аргументов запуска или чего-то такого?

Answer (score 4):

У дискорда для этого есть API под названием [Discord Rich Presense](https://discord.com/developers/docs/rich-presence/how-to).

Прочитав про него и прогуглив про эту технологию, я выяснил следующее:

Под капотом она использует RPC (Remote Procedure Call) для обмена данными между Discord и приложениями/играми. А RPC это Удалённый Вызов Процедур, технология которая позволяет программам вызывать функции или процедуры в другом адресном пространстве (программе). И именно она позволяет приложениям отправлять информацию о текущем статусе пользователя и получать обновления от Discord.

Ну и еще конечно же Вебсокеты, так как она обеспечивает более мгновенное и эффективное обновление статуса и активности пользователя в игре. Когда игрок начинает играть или меняет активность, это сообщение отправляется через WebSocket и отображается в реальном времени.

По факту говоря, ребята из Discord создали API в котором разработчики игр используют это API чтобы отправлять данные дискорду через RPC и Вебсокеты (Какая игра, какая миссия, итд)

Я думаю что следует копать в направлении изучения их технологии Rich Presense ну и на форумах найти материалы, а может даже и исходники реализации этого функционала.

Также помимо всего, как указал [@Exord](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/370745/exord) нужно учесть что Discord использует фреймворк [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/). Следовательно там есть прослойка ноды, которая может работать с системой. Вот к примеру работа с `WMI` - [github.com/jpgrusling/node-wmi](https://github.com/jpgrusling/node-wmi). И для трекинга процессов можно поиграться с `Win32_Process()`.
И еще на Windows можно узнать процессы юзера при помощи команды:

```
wmic process get description, processid
```

Ну а по поводу добавления программ вручную в Discord, программа использует API самой ОС, вдобавок к этому я нашел информацию о том что у них есть база данных приложений где Discord понимает какое именно приложение ты запустил. А если этого приложения нет в их базе данных, то при добавлении приложения она добавляется локальную базу данных Discord, где и храниться название самого приложения, где храняться его данные, детали итд. И всё это обрабатывает их [ActivityManager](https://discord.com/developers/docs/game-sdk/activities) чтобы верно показывать статус пользователя, и она работает вместе с Rich Presense.

Также еще на просторах интернета я нашел исходник какого-то разработчика, кто написал схожий по функционалу Activity Manager дискорда, [вот ссылка на сам репозиторий](https://github.com/alairon/discord-activity-manager)

Comment: Но насколько я понял, этот способ всё равно требует явного завершения процесса.

Comment: И как тогда я могу через сам дискорд добавлять приложения, где явно нет поддержки этого? Хоть тот же эксель.

Comment: Получается без tcp (веб сокетов) не обойтись. Но тогда где явное выделение порта?

Comment: В случае если нет поддержки этого API, дискорд может посмотреть процессы запущенные от текущего юзера. В винде это можно сделать через WMI. В линухе через ps aux, наример

Comment: под капотом discord имеет electron. Следовательно там есть прослойка ноды, которая может работать с системой. Вот к примеру работа с WMI - https://github.com/jpgrusling/node-wmi . Для процессов можно поиграться с Win32_Process()

Comment: Узнать процессы юзера на винде можно даже через CMD: например так "wmic process get description, processid"

Comment: @mister_svinia По поводу добавления програм вручную Дискорд использует API самой ОС, где упомянул Exord, плюс я прочитал что у них есть база данных приложений где он понимает какое именно приложение ты запустил. А если этого нет в базе, возможно она сохраняет в локальную базу данных дискорда, где и храниться название самого приложения, детали итд. И всё это обрабатывает их [ActivityManager](https://discord.com/developers/docs/game-sdk/activities) чтобы верно показывать статус пользователя, она работает вместе с Rich Presense

Comment: @mister_svinia А еще я нашел исходник какого-то чела кто написал схожий по функционалу Activity manager дискорда, [вот ссылка на сам репозиторий](https://github.com/alairon/discord-activity-manager)

Comment: Вот хорошо бы было-бы внести это всё в ответ. Баллы я и так передам, заслуженно. Только время пройдёт.

Comment: @mister_svinia Обновил ответ